# Static Image of Open Street map not showing clear

Tags: openstreetmap

Can someone help me or guide me to show clear static image of open street map.
I am using following code.

http://staticmap.openstreetmap.de/staticmap.php?center=40,-50&zoom=2&size=500x350

Comment: the image looks good, what is exactly the problem?

Comment: My cleint wants to display more clear the same image.. so is it possible

Comment: If you look in two the map font, the font is not showing clear.

Comment: The font is exactly how the map creators defined it, this the default map css of OpenStreet map. You can choose a different one, but then you'll have to do your own rendering, but there are different rendered map alternative in the OpenStreetmap universe, you just need to do some research

Comment: Thanks , But I need static map I mean dynamic image of the map so is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize the rendering of OpenStreetMap data if you don't like that rendering.
For example you could design the map as your client likes with Tilemill (https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and then use MapBox APIs (https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-static-api/).

If you only need an image, Tilemill can export directly a static image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a custom font on your map you'll have to go a commercial provider [Tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) or [MapCreator](http://developer.skobbler.com/mapcreator) (2 of the most popular)

As a side note: both offer retina ready static maps (so that the fonts will look good also on retina/xxhdpi devices)